# How Can I Save the Indexed Data with Elasticsearch Permanently?

Tags: search, indexing, elasticsearch, client, settings

I followed the ElasticSearch Java-Api Guide.I added Java_Home to Computer->Settings->Advanced Settings->Environment Variables.And I run ElasticSearch -> elasticsearch-service-x64.exe and run as administrator elasticsearch.bat.When I did these settings ,I wrote localhost:9200 to browser and I got information abaout my client or node I guess.After a while I wrote localhost:9200 again but this time anything showed up.
I dont know is it the reason of my problem.But I know I cant keep indexed data permanently.When I indexed , data is going away in 5 seconds and searching operation dont give me any Hits.Meanwhile please tolerate my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to SOLR, elasticsearch has no notion of a commit, so everything you feed to the server without error gets indexed.

Comment: I waited 20 minute then run only searching operation ,it works correctly, giving Hits .But in some trials giving 0 Hit then trying again ,gives Hit.. How is it possible ? What is the logic of Elastic search indexing ?

Comment: If you have the time, I'd suggest you watch a video or two (you mentioned, that your english isn't so good, so that might be a problem) - http://www.elasticsearch.org/videos/ or read the documentation. In the end, ES has - like any search engine - some [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) data structure at its core.

Comment: I solved the problem.elasticsearch.bat must remain open.Thanx anyway.